# Dlib shape predictor for detecting another shapes

Tags: shapes, dlib

I want to ask can I implement dlib c++ library do detect not face shape but train to detect another shapes? 
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

First prepare your data using this tool : [imglab](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/tree/master/tools/imglab)

Then train your own shape predictor using: [train shape predictor](http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor.py.html)